# ScriptCS with Sublime

Tags: c#, sublimetext2, scriptcs

I'm getting the exception in Sublime:

> Unbehandelte Ausnahme: [Decode error - output not cp1252]

by running this code:

```
Console.WriteLine("fsdfsd")
```

I installed Sublime Text 2 and 3 by installer and scriptcs by Chocolatey.

Then I added a file with following content:

```
{
 "cmd": ["C:\\Chocolatey\\lib\\ScriptCs.0.5.1\\tools\\scriptcs\\scriptcs.exe", "$file"],
 "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
 "encoding": "cp1252"
 }
```

as a scripts.sublime-build in Packages\User

How can I rid of it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8):

You should install the [scriptcs sublime plugin](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/scriptcs) (**Package Control: Install Package > scriptcs**) which includes syntax highlighting, some snippets and a build system (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>). You can find the source code for the plugin [here](https://github.com/scriptcs/scriptcs-sublime). I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately it feels quite slow (13.4s to build and run a 5 line parse and print statement) - any idea if this is normal?

Comment: That sounds like way too long... But remember, this is a compiled language, scriptcs will still compile (in-memory) before executing the code. File an issue at https://github.com/scriptcs/scriptcs/issues so we can investigate/debug it further :)

Answer (score 1):

change `"encoding": "cp1252"` to `"encoding": "utf-8"`